# Python library/framework to write an application that sends emails periodically

Tags: python, email, frameworks, reddit

I am considering to write an application that would covert the comments in reddit threads ([example](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/9tebz/pje_is_about_to_make_a_new_release_of_setuptools/)) to emails. The idea is to parse the reddit json data ([example](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/9tebz/pje_is_about_to_make_a_new_release_of_setuptools/.json)) and send new comments as plain EMails to subscribed users. One of the users can be gmane, so you can also read the comments over there. The motivation for writing this tool is to read reddit comments in our favorite EMail client (with filters and what not) without having to refresh the reddit thread.

Which library/framework is best suited for this task? To get it done faster? With minimal code?

Answer (score 1):

I would go with AppEngine to tackle this: integrated cron + email support.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Flexget](http://flexget.com/) to parse RSS feeds and email them.
You can get ideas from there.

Answer (score 0):

[Lamson](http://lamsonproject.org/) aims to be an 'email app framework' (taking after the recent developments in web app frameworks). It seems like it would be a good fit for the problem you describe.

Comment: Lamson is an email server meant for processing incoming messages.  I don't think it'd offer much for sending outgoing messages.

Comment: It does process incoming messages, but it definitely does have features for sending messages. Check the documentation:

http://lamsonproject.org/docs/getting_started.html

http://lamsonproject.org/docs/html_email_generation.html

http://lamsonproject.org/docs/lamson_commands.html